# Can I use a Bean as a model in grails instead of a Map?

Tags: grails, groovy, controller

**Short Question:** I'd like to use a typed bean as a model in grails instead of a Map. Is this possible?

I'd like to do this:

```
def index = {
   new Person(firstName:"foo", lastName:"bar", age:30)
}
```

Instead of this:

```
def index = {
    [firstName:"foo", lastName:"bar", age:30]
}
```

**Long Question:** I'm maintinaing a controller written by other developers and it's really difficult to understand all of the possible entries in the model. The model is populated over a number of methods. I'd like to refactor the controller to return a custom bean as the model but I was hoping that the gsp would not need to be changed.

I assumed that grails could handle either a map or a bean as a model but soon realised that passing a bean to the gsp resulted in NullPointerExceptions as properties could not be found.

I realise that my controller can return a map like:

```
[model: myBean]
```

But then I would need to go through the gsp and change all references from ${someProp} to ${model.someProp}.

I'm also aware that I can use reflection to convert my bean to a Map but I'd prefer not to do this either.

Comment: Why cant the map be `[someProp: new Person()]` ??

Comment: I was hoping to just change the controller code and leave the GSP as is. This would require me to go through the GSP replacing all ${firstName} with ${someProp.firstName}. This is not a simple find-and-replace because some local variables in the GSP would not need to be prefixed.

Answer (score 2):

See [render](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html) doc reference. You can find in examples

```
// render a template to the response for the specified bean
def theShining = new Book(title: 'The Shining', author: 'Stephen King')
render(template: "book", bean: theShining)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a workable solution but requires me to explicitly state the template. Is there any way I can keep the functionality where the template is derived from the method name?

Comment: So is 'bean' a reserved property name in the map? Or will I then need to use ${bean.firstName} in my GSP?

Comment: @uklance it's a bit ugly but you could say `render(view:actionName, bean:new Person(...))` - the `actionName` variable in a controller resolves to the name of the current action, which is what it would use for the default view name.

Comment: It's not a property in map. It's param passed to view. Try to use ${bean.firstName} and let me know

Comment: Unfortunately, render(view:'index', bean:new Person(...)) does not work. The properties (firstName, lastName etc) are null in the GSP. NB: I am using grails 1.3.7. I tried adding getters and setters for the properties (previously public fields) but that does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your controller: (Note this will return all properties)

```
New Person().properties
```